# How to add buttons to android navigation bar (not bottom bar)

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I learn how to cuztomize the android navigation bar?

I know that it is not recommended because of the material ui commandments (but I wanna do it anyways).

There is a few applications out there who supports this - and I was looking into them to see if I can learn it from them.

### Lichess

I know a chess app called lichess which added 2 buttons in each side of the navigation bar - and the code is [open source on github](https://github.com/ornicar/lila/), but I can't find where the specific buttons are implemented. Also many things in the app is developen in typescript and scala with a wierd html dls.

**Edit**
I see that lichess is implemented in webview and they might just have created their own "fake" navigation bar in typescript.

---

### CustomNavigationBar

Also there is another app called CuztomNavigationBar which should be able to change the settings for the android navigation bar on a global scale, so that it will persist after the app is closed.
This code is not open source so I cannot find out how he did it. [Here is a tutorial how to use his app](https://beebom.com/customize-navigation-bar-android/)

Thank you in advance

Here is a image of the bottombar on lichess.

[image]

Comment: Just wanna suggest that you should directly ask the owners as that is a large projects and many contributors there could help answer you. I checked the Discussion page and already found your question posted.

Comment: yes I asked them already :-) If they answer me I will share the answer here on SO

Comment: I don't think that the lichess repo you linked is the correct one. That's the repo for the main game server. A quick search led me to [this one, "the lichess.org official application"](https://github.com/veloce/lichobile), but it's just a basic `WebView` wrapper. Is that the one you're referring to? I didn't really dig any further into it, 'cause I don't see anything in the screenshots or in brief look at the code that would do what you're describing.

Comment: Ah I see, could it be that the "android navigation bar" that we see in this app is not even a real android navigation bar but a fake one they made inside the webview :D

Comment: I was wrong about that being a simple `WebView` wrapper, now that I look at it again. I will say, though, however they're doing that, it doesn't appear to be in the `android/` sources. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks I will take a good look :)

Comment: Here's an XDA article that explains how the Custom Navigation Bar app is doing it: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-change-your-nav-bar-icons-or-re-arrange-the-buttons-without-root/. The first part is basically the same thing as the page you link above, but the technical details are after that.

Comment: Wow thank you - it looks like alot of good information. They even write that is was implemented in the `Android O Developer Preview may have toyed around with its hidden navigation bar customizer located in the SystemUI Tuner.`

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure how useful Custom Navigation Bar's technique will be for your design, but if anybody should want to play around with that, [`NavigationBarInflaterView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android11-release/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NavigationBarInflaterView.java) is what parses that Settings string to build the UI. The source shows a few more possible actions, as well as a small "markup" for fine-tuning the visual arrangement. (I linked Android 11; not all options are available in earlier versions.)

Comment: I installed lichess mobile to investigate that, but those extra buttons did not show in my test devices. Is there some setting that I missed? What specifically does each of those buttons do on yours?

Comment: The one to the left is a kind of menu and the one to the right is a lock screen button

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I just recently learned that those extra buttons on the navigation bar are from Samsung's Game Booster thingamajig. They aren't actually in the bar itself; they're `View`s added directly to `WindowManager` as system overlays. AFAIK, regular apps can't do system overlays any more – since about API level 26, I think – so that method's probably not really a feasible option for most. Just FYI. Cheers!